# Change volume of all sounds in document

Tags: javascript, volume, audio

i have a little question: is there a way how to change volume of all sounds in document with JavaScript (like <video>, <embed>, <object>,...)?

**EDIT**

I want to change the volume in document like <body volume="0.5">...Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay,

Here is How I'll do it:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  Master Audio Controller:-
  <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1.0" id="range">
  <span id="range_value">1.0</span>
  <br/>
  <video controls autoplay loop name="media" class="myVolumeClass">
    <source src="http://www.rbg.wz.cz/adventure/sounds/step.wav" type="audio/x-wav">
  </video>
  <br/>
  <video controls autoplay loop name="media" class="myVolumeClass">
    <source src="http://www.rbg.wz.cz/adventure/sounds/step.wav" type="audio/x-wav">
  </video>
  <br/>
  <video controls autoplay loop name="media" class="myVolumeClass">
    <source src="http://www.rbg.wz.cz/adventure/sounds/step.wav" type="audio/x-wav">
  </video>
  <br/>
</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function updateVolume() {
  const newVolume = document.getElementById('range').value;
  document.querySelectorAll('video, audio, embed, object').forEach(element => element.volume = newVolume)
  document.getElementById('range_value').innerText = newVolume
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  /* I'll Suggest to use $(document).ready(function(){ }); If Using JQuery */
  document.getElementById('range').addEventListener('input', updateVolume)
}
```

[**Here is a demo of this code**](http://jsfiddle.net/t3pk1xco/1/).

Hope it helps, cheers :)!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you. +1.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can give all those elements the same class (or find a similar way to select them all), and then do something like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myVolumeClass');
var myDesiredVolume = 0.3;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].volume = myDesiredVolume;
}
```

Note: code not tested

---

Basically, it's all about modifying their volume property.

Comment: ok, i tested your code, but it still doesn't work for all the document, JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t3pk1xco/

Comment: Hm, works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/t3pk1xco/3/ I've set the starting volume to 30%. I see you want to change it on runtime, it should work the same way - loop through all the object and set the **new** volume for each. I'm not sure what are you trying to do now.